# How to send log entries to a remote server running journald (systemd)

Tags: linux, logging, remote, systemd, syslog

I have an iot module running a firmware that has the capability of sending the logs to a remote syslog host. I've already configured it to send the entries to an Ubuntu Server running rsyslog. 
I'd like to know which would be the best practice here for these logs to be merged into journald scope, since when logged into the server, if I'd like to check remote logs in the context of other local logs, I have to manually inspect /var/log/syslog (file where rsyslog is storing entries) and the output of journalctl command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rsyslog has a plugin to output events to journal.

It is called [omjournal](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omjournal.html)

Here is an example configuration for [Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/s1-interaction_of_rsyslog_and_journal.html)

I don't know whether it can output `rsyslog` events directly from your `iot` to a remote `systemd` machine or that it can only import `rsyslog` events from your `iot` on your local machine and then output them to `journal`.

Comment: That's just nice, I'll definitely try it. This is like a pipeline of log entries, that follows the virtual path `rsyslogd:tcp_port -> rsyslogd.omjournal -> journald`. I'm wondering, is journald capable of listening for log entries from a tcp/udp port like rsyslog?